# Simple file parsing in shell

Tags: shell, parsing

Given a `version` file in the following format:

```
major=1
minor=2
patch=3
```

I need a shell function or a one-liner to read this file and generate a version string in the format `$major.$minor.$patch`. Something along the lines of:

```
awk '{ parse print result }' version
```

Comment: You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all.  IMO, one-liners are a maintenance nightmare. Write a function, and then you have something better than a one-liner. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Will this do? If I had more I would not ask the question.

Comment: @shellter A function will do as well, just rephrased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
source ./version; echo $major.$minor.$patch
```

is as simple as it gets. This assumes the `version` file contains only valid shell code, such as a list of variable assignments.

Comment: The file is well behaved. Thanks. I would need to do this for a number of files in a loop. Would it matter for the choice between source and eval?

Comment: Typically, stay away from `eval` (what if the file includes `rm -rf /`?). If you don't want to pollute your current environment, run it in a subshell. e.g. `( your code here )`.